# User is able to enter blank spaces as input in input paramater in js file

Tags: javascript, wcs

I want to apply validation where user cannot input name starting from blank space, in my present code whe user is giving value using spacebar its successfully entering blank value.
I want to apply validation where user can use space but not in the beginning

```
if($('#workspaceNameUpdate').val().trim().length == 0 && $('#workspaceNameUpdate').val() === "") {  
 $('#workspaceNameUpdate').addClass('error');
 $('#workspaceNameUpdateError').removeClass('hidden');
}
```

I am using trim class but its not working its not entering into the error block!

Comment: Why you don't simply trim it ? blank spaces at the begining/end is usually a user mistake, and you can safely discard them

Comment: No i cannot simply trim that how can i use this as a validation

Comment: You can do something like `str.trim().length == str.length`

Comment: No its not working
 if($('#workspaceNameUpdate').val().trim().length == $('#workspaceNameUpdate').val().length && $('#workspaceNameUpdate').val() === "")
Are you saying like this ?

Comment: no i don't mean like this, use `str.trim().length == str.length` to validate that the string does not contain blank spaces, if you need to display an error message when the validation fail, you can use something like  `str.trim().length != str.length`. And if you have extra cases you need to use OR (`||`) not AND (`&&`)

Comment: [Java is not JavaScript!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there should be || instead of &&

```
$('#workspaceNameUpdate').val().trim().length == 0
```

because the first part is trimming and then checking the length - which is right

but the second part `$('#workspaceNameUpdate').val() === ""` - is comparing that value and "   " != ""

solution - I think the first check will handle everything and there is no need of second check

Comment: Yes its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex when you want to validate the input-

```
/^(?![\s-])[\w\s-]+$/
```

Below is two working examples to check whether space is at the beginning or middle or end.

1. On character input -

```js
function validate(input) {
  console.log(/^(?![\s-])[\w\s-]+$/.test(input));
}
```

```html
<input oninput="validate(this.value)" label="enter name">
```

2. Custom input-

```js
function validate(input) {
   console.log(/^(?![\s-])[\w\s-]+$/.test(input));
}

// two blank space at the beginning (fail)
validate("   firstname");
// one blank space at the beginning (fail)
validate(" firstname");
// blank space at the middle (pass)
validate("firstname   lastname");
// blank space at the last (pass)
validate("firstname   ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a regex check like this -

```
if(/^\s/.test(yourInput.value))
```